# Connecting language change to url change in a different file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, internationalization

I have implemented react-i18next into my app, and i need to connect the change language button to change the url in different routes of the app which embedd Tableau.

Here is what im trying to do:

View where a tableau dashboard is embedded and i defined the variables and changeDashboardLng():

```
import React from 'react'
import "../App.css"
import TableauView from 'insights-tableau';
import i18next from "i18next";
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar/Navbar';

const lng = i18next.language;
const dashboardUrl = "https://isr-tableau/views/Demo/Monitoring";

function MonitoringOverview() {

  const changeDashboardLng = (lng) => {
    if(lng === "fr"){
      dashboardUrl = "https://isr-tableau/views/DemoFR/Monitoring"
    }
    
  }
  return(<div className='MainDashboard'>
     <div className='dashboard-container'>
      <TableauView  src={dashboardUrl} toolbar="hidden"/>
      </div>
    </div> )


}

export default MonitoringOverview
```

This is Navbar.js where the change language button resides:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { NavbarData } from "./NavbarData";
import { IconContext } from "react-icons";
import "./Navbar.css";
import Hamburger from "./Icons/Hamburger.svg";
import "./Icons/p_logo_color.png";
import Persona from "./Icons/Persona.svg";
import Logout from "./Icons/Logout.svg";








import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';








//Navbar function
function Navbar() {
  const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false);
  const showSidebar = () => setSidebar(!sidebar);
  const [pageName, setPageName] = useState('Operational Overview');
  const location = useLocation();
  

  //i18n

  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
  const lngs = {
    en: {nativeName: 'English'},
    fr: {nativeName: 'French'}
  };
  
  

  

  const getPageTitleByUrl = (path) => {
    NavbarData.filter((navItem) => {
  
      if(navItem.path === path) {
        setPageName(navItem.title);
      }
      return (true)
    } )

  };

  const userConfigPageTitle = (path) => {
    setPageName("User Information");

  }

  

  useEffect(() => {
    if(location.pathname) {
      getPageTitleByUrl(location.pathname);
    }
  }, [location] ); 


  

  return (
    <>
      <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: "undefined" }}>
        <div className="navbar">
          <Link to="#" className="menu-bars">
             <img src={Hamburger} alt="hamburger" onClick={showSidebar} />
          </Link>
          <div className="criminal-records">{t("navbar.criminalRecords")}</div> 

          <div className="pageTitle"><h1>{t("navbar." + pageName)}</h1></div>

        <div className="language-component"> 
        <div>
          {Object.keys(lngs).map((lng) => (
            <button key={lng} style={{ fontWeight: i18n.resolvedLanguage === lng ? 'bold' : 'normal' }} type="submit" onClick={() => i18n.changeLanguage(lng)}>
              {lngs[lng].nativeName}
            </button>
          ))}
        </div>
       
    
        
        

        </div>



          <Link to='userconfig' onClick={userConfigPageTitle}>
          <div><img className="userIcon" src={Persona} alt="persona" /> </div>
          <div className="userButton">User123#</div>
          </Link>
        
     
          <Link to='/' className="logout-button">
          <div className="right-side">
            <img className="logoutIcon" src={Logout} alt="persona" /> </div>
          <div className="logoutButton">{t("navbar.logout")}</div> 
          </Link>
        </div>
        <nav className={sidebar ? "nav-menu active" : "nav-menu"}>
          <ul className="nav-menu-items" onClick={showSidebar}>
        
            {NavbarData.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <li key={index} className={item.cName}>
                  <Link to={item.path}>
        
                    <span className="navbutton-text" ><span className="navbutton-icon">{item.icon}</span>{t("navbar." + item.title)}</span>
                    
                    
                  </Link>
                  
                </li>
                
              );
            })}

          </ul>
        </nav>
      </IconContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

This is i18n.js:

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';


i18n
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    debug: true,
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // not needed for react as it escapes by default
    },
    resources: {
      en: {
        translation: {
          login:{
            submit: "Login",
            labelUser: "Username",
            password: "Password",
            welcomeMessage: "Welcome to Pangea Insights Login Application",
            projectName: "Congo DRC Operational Process",
            loginPlease: "Login please",
            
            


          },
          navbar: {
            criminalRecords: "Criminal Records |",
            logout: "Logout",
            "operationalOverview": "Operational Overview",
            "performanceQuality": "Performance Quality",
            "fraudAndAnomalies": "Fraud and Anomalies",


            "urlMonitoringOverview": "https://isr-tableau/views/CongoDemo/Monitoring"


          }
        }
      },
      fr: {
        translation: {
          login:{
            submit: "Se connecte",
            labelUser: "Nom d'utilisateur",
            password: "Mot de passe",
            welcomeMessage: "Bienvenue à l'Application de Insights",
            projectName: "Congo DRC Processus Opérationnel",
            loginPlease: "Connectez-vous"




          },
          navbar:{

            criminalRecords: "Casiers Judiciaires |",
            logout: "Se déconnecter",
            "operationalOverview": "Aperçu Opérationnel",
            "performanceQuality": "Qualité des Performances",
            "fraudAndAnomalies": "Fraudes et Anomalies",
            "urlMonitoringOverview": "https://isr-tableau/views/CongoDemoFR/Monitoring"
     



          }
        }
      }
      
  }});

export default i18n;
```

and also index.js to understand the structure of the app:

```
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
  Outlet,
} from "react-router-dom";



import "./i18n";
import {Suspense} from "react"; 
import React from "react";




import MonitoringOverview from "./routes/MonitoringOverview";
import PerformanceQuality from "./routes/PerformanceQuality";
import Finance from "./routes/Finance";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar/Navbar";
import "./App.css";
import LoginScreen from "./routes/LoginScreen/LoginScreen";
import UserConfig from "./routes/UserConfig/UserConfig.js";
import Simulation from "./routes/Simulation";
import Fraud from "./routes/Fraud";


const AppLayout = () => {


  return (
    <React.StrictMode>
    <Suspense fallback={null}>
  <>
    <Navbar />
    <Outlet />
  </>
  </Suspense>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

}








const router = createBrowserRouter([
  
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <LoginScreen />
  },
  
  
  {
    element: <AppLayout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "monitoringoverview",
        element: <MonitoringOverview />,
      },
  
      {
        path: "performancequality",
        element: <PerformanceQuality />,
      },

      {
        path: "finance",
        element: <Finance />,
      },
      {
        path: "simulation",
        element: <Simulation />,
      },
      {
        path: 'userconfig',
        element: <UserConfig />
      },
      {
        path: 'fraud',
        element: <Fraud />
      },


      
    ],
  },
]);



createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <RouterProvider router={router} />
  
);
```

Basically what i need now is to let the onClick() of the change button language activate the changeDashboardLng(); aswell as the changeLanguage(); which affects the MonitoringOverview.js

How can i achieve this? am i on the right path or should i take a different approach? can i make the changeDashboardLng static (im not sure how this concept applies here actually)

Thanks in advance!